# Core Plot Linker error building for testing

Tags: ios, linker-errors, core-plot

I am running Xcode 9 with Swift 3.2 and am trying to Build for testing an iOS app. It builds and runs fine in the development environment, but when I build for testing to submit to App Store I get 2 linker errors. 1) framework not found CorePlot for architecture armv7, and 2) Framework not found CorePlot for architecture arm64.

I have removed re-installed into my app CorePlot 2.2 via pod install multiple times, but still get this error. Any suggestion as to how to resolve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Look at architecture, that use then you build CorePlot library. (You can find it in the Pod project).

Comment: thanks. Will try that.

Comment: I am not sure how I did it, but I rebuilt the CorePlot library making sure that the correct architecture was used, and now it works. Thank you for the answer. App is now out for beta testing